# How to toggle ul class when anchor tag is clicked using jquery?

Tags: jquery, toggle

I want to keep a toggle function for `ul` `li` `a`. In magento I used the below coding to fetch `level 1` and `level 2` subcategories in layered navigation:

```
<ul class="level0">
    <?php foreach ($cats as $cat): ?>
        <li class="level1">
            <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($cat) ?>">
                <?php echo $cat->getName() ?>
            </a>
            <?php $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cat->getId()) ?>
            <?php $_subcategories = $_category->getChildrenCategories() ?>
            <?php if (count($_subcategories) > 0): ?>

                <ul class="level1" style="display:none;">
                    <?php foreach ($_subcategories as $_subcategory): ?>
                        <li class="level2">
                            <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_subcategory) ?>">
                                <?php echo $_subcategory->getName() ?>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </ul>

            <?php endif; ?>
        </li>

    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

I want to toggle and display the `ul.level1` when the `a` anchor tag of `level1` is clicked.SO I used the jquery below:

```
<script>
    var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

    $j(function () {
        $j('li.level1 a').click(function () {

            $j('ul.level1:visible').hide();
            $j('ul.level1', this).toggle();
        });
    });
</script>
```

But it is not displaying the `ul.level1` when `li.level1 a` is clicked. It is toggling when `li.level1` is clicked. Why is this happening an help me to resolve this isuue please.

Comment: `$j(this).parent('ul.level1').toggle();` try this

Comment: @guradio how will `.parent('ul.level1')` work!!? did u mean : `.parent().find("ul.level1")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `siblings()`

```
$(this).siblings("ul.level1").toggle();
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/28dmpu1s/).

```js
$('li.level1 a').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings("ul.level1").toggle();
});
```

```css
.level1{
  color:green;
}
.level2{
  color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="level0">
<li class="level1">
  <a href="#">Toggle</a>
  <ul class="level1" style="display:none;">
  <li class="level2"><a href="#">Level2</a></li>
  <li class="level2"><a href="#">Level2</a></li>
  <li class="level2"><a href="#">Level2</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li class="level1">
  <a href="#">Toggle</a>
  <ul class="level1" style="display:none;">
  <li class="level2"><a href="#">Level2</a></li>
  <li class="level2"><a href="#">Level2</a></li>
  <li class="level2"><a href="#">Level2</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li class="level1">
  <a href="#">Toggle</a>
  <ul class="level1" style="display:none;">
  <li class="level2"><a href="#">Level2</a></li>
  <li class="level2"><a href="#">Level2</a></li>
  <li class="level2"><a href="#">Level2</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you. How to keep the selected or clicked `ul.level1` open even when the page reloads?

Comment: For that you will have to maintain the state of which all `ul`s are open and after reload you will have to only hide those, that were not open.

Comment: You can do that by using cookie or local db(local storage) if you want to do it on client side.

Comment: That will be a different question all together. You can resolve(mark) this and post another question.

Comment: here is the link for my new question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37990391/how-to-show-an-ul-when-a-particular-li-is-clicked-using-jquery

Please help