# How to show an ul when a particular li is clicked using jquery?

Tags: html-lists, toggle

I want to show the `ul` class of `li` which is clicked.
My html is:

```
 <ul id="level1" class="category">
    <li class="level1 inactive">
      <a href="#">abc</a>
      <ul id="level2" style=" display:none;">
      <li class="level2 inactive"><a href="#">Level2</a></li>
      <li class="level2 inactive"><a href="#">Level2</a></li>
      <li class="level2 inactive"><a href="#">Level2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="level1 inactive">
      <a href="#">xyz</a>
      <ul id="level2" style=" display:none;">
      <li class="level2 inactive"><a href="#">Level2</a></li>
      <li class="level2 inactive"><a href="#">Level2</a></li>
      <li class="level2 inactive"><a href="#">Level2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="level1 inactive">
      <a href="#">bcd</a>
      <ul id="level2" style=" display:none;">
      <li class="level2 inactive"><a href="#">Level2</a></li>
      <li class="level2 inactive"><a href="#">Level2</a></li>
      <li class="level2 inactive"><a href="#">Level2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
```

the js which I use to show the `ul` is below:

```
<script>  
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(function() {
  $j('li.level1').click(function() {
      $j(this).addClass("current").removeClass("inactive");
      $j('ul#level2:visible').hide();
      $j('ul#level2').toggle();
  });

});
</script>
```

css:

```
   ul.category li.level1.current a{background:url("../images/left_menu_new.png") no-repeat scroll 10px -285px transparent;}
    .active{display:block;}
```

When I click the `li.level1` `current` class design is added to every `li` of `level1` , `ul` inside the selected `li` is  opened and as it has anchor tag the page is redirected to the `url` inside the anchor tag .

What I want is when I click the `li` the `current` class should be added only to the selected `li` & the page of respective `url` in the anchor tag should be opened and `ul` of selected `li` should be opened there.

Kindly guide me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

For you to achieve this, you will have to take advantage of location hash.
Do the following :

1. On your anchor tags, that toggle your ul, add href to a dummy unique value. Make sure the value is same as the id of the `li` you are in.

> ```
> <ul class="level0">
>       <li class="level1" id="li1">
>           <a href="#li1">Toggle.1</a>
>           <ul class="level1" style="display:none;">
> ```

2. When ever page loads, read window location hash.

> `var li = window.location.hash;`

3. If hash is found, show the related `ul`.

> ```
> if(li!=""){
>   $(li + " ul").show();
> }
> ```

This way you will be able to show the last opened `ul` by the user.

```js
$(function() {
  var li = window.location.hash;
  if (li != "") {
    $(li + " ul").show();
  }
  $('li.level1 a').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().siblings().each(function() {
      $(this).find("ul.level1").hide();
    });
    $(this).siblings("ul.level1").show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="level0">
  <li class="level1" id="li1">
    <a href="#li1">Toggle.1</a>
    <ul class="level1" style="display:none;">
      <li class="level2"><a href="#">Level2.1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="level2"><a href="#">Level2.1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="level2"><a href="#">Level2.1</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="level1" id="li2">
    <a href="#li2">Toggle.2</a>
    <ul class="level1" style="display:none;">
      <li class="level2"><a href="#">Level2.2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="level2"><a href="#">Level2.2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="level2"><a href="#">Level2.2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="level1" id="li3">
    <a href="#li3">Toggle.3</a>
    <ul class="level1" style="display:none;">
      <li class="level2"><a href="#">Level2.3</a>
      </li>
      <li class="level2"><a href="#">Level2.3</a>
      </li>
      <li class="level2"><a href="#">Level2.3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hey I already have a unique url for the anchor tag. And the toggle didnt work for the above code.

Comment: So do you have the same url hash as the id of the `li` ?

Comment: no i dont have any url for li. I have the url for anchor tag within li

Comment: Please carefully check the code under point number 1 in my answer.

Comment: Check the id of li and href of a elements. They are same. Thats what I am asking you.

Comment: yes i gave it following your guidance. but didnt work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115489/discussion-between-ramya-and-himanshu-tyagi).